# iOS - Trying to save a PDF to the device and Load using a Webview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, nsurl

I am fairly new at this and tried to solve this problem for quite some time now. I  want to download a file from a url and save it to the document folder on the device. After that I want to load it to a Webview. The webview part seems to work if I copy a file manually but when I save the URL it shows only 5529 bytes saved with the correct file name?

Down the road I will need to tackle loading file from a secure web-server, hence the connection Authenticate methods.

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize webView;
@synthesize webData;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}


-(void)handleDocumentOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [webView loadRequest:req];
}
-(void)loadFileFromDocumentFolder:(NSString *) filename
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *file = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
    NSURL *urlPdf = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: file];
    [self handleDocumentOpenURL:urlPdf];

}
- (IBAction)btnSave:(id)sender
{
    NSString *urlString = @"http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/UIWebView_Class.pdf";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSURLConnection *urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

    if (urlConnection)
    {
       webData = [NSMutableData data];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error !" message:@"Error has occured, please verify internet connection"  delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [alert show];

    }
}
- (IBAction)btnLoad:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self loadFileFromDocumentFolder:@"test.pdf"];
}

#pragma mark - NSURLConnection Delegate Methods
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{

        [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"did fail");
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{

    NSLog(@"did receive data");
    [webData appendData:data];
    }
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"did receive response");
    [webData setLength:0];
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    BOOL isSuccessfull;
    NSLog(@"did finish loading. Bytes Received: %d", [webData length]);

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *pdfPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.pdf"];

    isSuccessfull = [webData writeToFile:pdfPath atomically:YES];

}
@end
```

Comment: I can't load the file. It does not save correctly (only 5529 bytes). I can see the file there but when I try to load, I get :"failed to find PDF header: `%PDF' not found."

Comment: Are you able to examine the raw file contents to see what kind of data has been saved?

Comment: I can access the file with a text editor and see that I only got some header data from the file:iOS Developer Library — Pre-Release   Apple Developer
Search
Search iOS Developer Library

PDF Companion File
 • 
 •

Comment: I looked at the headers coming back from that URL using "curl" at the command line, which makes me suspect you need to look into how to handle redirect requests from the server.  (Not something I've done.)

Comment: @PhillipMills, I am not sure I understand what you mean. Are you talking about credentials or something different?

Comment: Well, @PhillipMills, I looked at this Curl tool and it helped me understand very quickly that I was testing with the wrong file at this point. As of now I can save a file and load it to the Webview. Now I need to figure out how to do that from a secure server.

Comment: I'm glad to hear you're making progress.  (I came to this question originally because of having experience with PDFs in a web view not so much because of server interaction.)

Comment: How did you solve this issue? I am also stuck with it. Please help me if you can.

Comment: Hi @Manthan, its been a while since I looked at this code but I am posting my solution here. Let me know if this is not what you're looking for.

Comment: 'code'{
        
            [self.view bringSubviewToFront:webView];
        
        NSURL * urlOther = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputPath];
        NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest     requestWithURL:urlOther];
        [webView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [webView loadRequest:req];
    
        [self.view addSubview:webView];
    }
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:btnBack];
    [btnBack setEnabled:YES];

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply.I got my solution over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21874538/failed-to-download-and-open-a-pdf-file-with-error-failed-to-find-pdf-header-in-i/21875240#21875240.

Comment: Great. Glad it works for you.