# Failed to download and open a PDF file with error failed to find PDF header in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, ios7, webview

I am having an app in which I am opening a PDF file from a url.

I am successfully able to open it in a webView.

Now I want to download that PDF file and save it in my documents folder and want to send that PDF file in my mail.

I searched a lot and found the best solution below.

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myfile.pdf"];

    if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]){

        NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:@"http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/UIWebView_Class.pdf"]];

        //Store the downloaded file  in documents directory as a NSData format
        [pdfData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    }


    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [webView setDelegate:self];
    webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

But when i try this code, it gives me  error saying **failed to find PDF header: `%PDF' not found**

I am even not able to open my PDF also.

I know same questions are asked before but I am not able to solve this error right now.

I don't know what I am doing wrong over here.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code for downloading & saving your pdf file

```
    UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

   [indicator startAnimating];

    NSLog(@"Downloading Started");
    NSString *urlToDownload = @"http://gradcollege.okstate.edu/sites/default/files/PDF_linking.pdf";
    NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlToDownload];
    NSURLRequest *request=[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowed timeoutInterval:120.0f];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {

        [indicator stopAnimating];

        if (!connectionError) {

            if ( data )
            {
                NSArray   *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

                NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"myfile.pdf"];

                //saving is done on main thread
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [data
                     writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
                    NSLog(@"File Saved !");

                    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
                    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
                    [_rssWebView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
                    //[_rssWebView setDelegate:self];
                    [_rssWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
                });
            }
        }

    }];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the thing is file got saved in document directories path and also get opened in webview but its size is only 1Kb. and it is not opening form there.

Comment: i have check it . actually the pdf link you tried to download is ssl protected. (paste this link in browser & it will convert to https://). i have check it with some random pdf link & it working fine.

Comment: Ok thanks. Can you please provide me any link which is working?

Comment: check my updated code here. i have made it asyn download, with activity indicator for testing. it works fine

Comment: any pdf link you can try that do not have "https://" in starting. [example link](http://gradcollege.okstate.edu/sites/default/files/PDF_linking.pdf)

Comment: Yes, I show that bro. Thanks sooo much man. Its done finally. I forgot to check that it was SSL protected. Thanks again. +1 for you.

Answer (score 0):

If convert to string server response, that you got in `NSData *pdfData`, you will see next:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>iOS Developer Library</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script>
        var content_page = "navigation";
        var href = window.location.href;
        if (window.location.href.match('#')) {
            var newhref = href.replace('#', '');
            newhref = newhref.replace('%23', '#');
          window.location.href = newhref;
        }
        else {
            console.log(content_page);
            console.log(content_page.match("content_page"));
            if(content_page.match("content_page")) {
                window.location.href = './navigation';
            }
            else {
                window.location.href = "./" + content_page;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>    
<body>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/library/webstats/pagetracker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if(typeof PageTracker !== 'undefined') {
  if(window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("load", function(){PageTracker.logPageLoad()},false);
  } else if(window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent("onload",function(){PageTracker.logPageLoad()});
  }
}
</script>
</html>
```

This only web page, which, as I can assume, will forward you to document with another URI:
`https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/UIWebView_Class.pdf`. So you must use this url if you want to download .pdf file

**Also**, pay attention on @pawan's answer, and use his approach to avoid download files in main thread